# Are the buildTypes parameters (buildConfigField) in build.gradle (app) sorted alphabetically?

Tags: android, gradle

The problem is the following: I'm setting some `buildConfigFields`, some of them depend on others, but, for some reason, I'm getting an `illegal forward reference` error in `BuildConfig` generated class. One of these fields is being placed before those on which it depends. But in `build.gradle` the order is consistent.

Some code below.

```
...
buildTypes {
    debug {
        buildConfigField "String", 'SERVER_ADDRESS', '"10.0.2.2"'
        buildConfigField "int", 'SERVER_PORT', '8080'
        buildConfigField "String", 'SERVER_URL', '"http://" + SERVER_ADDRESS + ":" + SERVER_PORT'
        buildConfigField "String", 'NOTIFICATION_SERVICE_URL', '"ws://" + SERVER_ADDRESS + ":" + SERVER_PORT + "/notification"'
        debuggable true
    }
...
}
```

And BuildConfig auto generated class sample:

```java
...
// Fields from build type: debug
public static final String NOTIFICATION_SERVICE_URL = "ws://" + SERVER_ADDRESS + ":" + SERVER_PORT + "/notification";
public static final String SERVER_ADDRESS = "10.0.2.2";
public static final int SERVER_PORT = 8080;
public static final String SERVER_URL = "http://" + SERVER_ADDRESS + ":" + SERVER_PORT;
...
```

As you can see, an `illegal forward reference`. I tried change the name to one beginning with the letter R and works fine, the illegal reference is gone. Is this right? Alphabetically ordered?

Comment: Try adding "BuildConfig." to places where you want expanded value. I.e.  buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_URL", '"http://" + BuildConfig.SERVER_ADDRESS + ":" + BuildConfig.SERVER_PORT'

Comment: Pls, Try this My solution

Answer (score 1):

What works is a format like below:

```
public static final String NOTIFICATION_SERVICE_URL = "ws://" + BuildConfig.SERVER_ADDRESS + ":" + BuildConfig.SERVER_PORT + "/notification";
public static final String SERVER_ADDRESS = "10.0.2.2";
public static final int SERVER_PORT = 8080;
public static final String SERVER_URL = "http://" + BuildConfig.SERVER_ADDRESS + ":" + BuildConfig.SERVER_PORT;
```

To achieve this, modify your `buildConfigField`s like so:

```
buildConfigField "String", 'SERVER_ADDRESS', '"10.0.2.2"'
buildConfigField "int", 'SERVER_PORT', '8080'
buildConfigField "String", 'SERVER_URL', '"http://" + BuildConfig.SERVER_ADDRESS + ":" + BuildConfig.SERVER_PORT'
buildConfigField "String", 'NOTIFICATION_SERVICE_URL', '"ws://" + BuildConfig.SERVER_ADDRESS + ":" + BuildConfig.SERVER_PORT + "/notification"'
```